# SQL statement - compare two tables columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and SQL.

I want to compare two table-columns.

This is what we have 
Table 1(`Review`) 
Table 2(`Customer`)

We want the Review_Customer_Id to be = to the Customer_Id in the Customer Table

How would you write this?

In my head it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_Id = Review_Customer_Id IN (SELECT Review_Customer_Id FROM Review);
```

Comment: Do you want to return rows from Customer, where the Customer_Id exists in the Review table?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_Id IN (SELECT Customer_Review_Id FROM Review);

Comment: I just want to display first and lastname of the author on the review from the customer table. 
When they create a review it add the Customer_Id in the review table.

Comment: Check this - SELECT (fistnameField + "" + LastnameField) AS Name FROM Customer
WHERE Customer_Id IN (SELECT Customer_Review_Id FROM Review);

Comment: @ms9778 i will put this as answer here, please find my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Answer

```
 SELECT (fistnameField + "" + LastnameField) AS Name FROM Customer WHERE Customer_Id IN (SELECT Customer_Review_Id FROM Review);
```